# Count occurrences of a column with alias in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a count of names and the id's associated with it
for example
Name : Jon Smith
cnt  : 2
Id   : 1

And the second John Smith record will have a different ID associated with it.

I have looked at other suggested solutions and have gotten this far:

```
select a.id, concat(a.firstname,' ',a.lastname) as name, b.cnt 
from table a
join (select concat(firstname,' ',lastname) as bname, count(*) as cnt 
            from table by firstname,lastname) b 
on a.name=b.bname
```

However, sql is giving an error saying invalid column name 'name'. 
I know I can get the desired results just using one column to get the counts and then do an subquery for the remaining columns to be placed back in. But I need it for the names

Comment: It's possible name could be a reserved word. try changing to fullname or it's possible you need to change the ON bit to say a.firstname = b.firstname and a.lastname = b.lastname instead of comparing the concatenated parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the alias in the `JOIN` condition. You can either put it in a subquery first, or use the concatenated columns as this:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) AS name,
    b.cnt
FROM table a
JOIN (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS bname,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table b
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
) b
    ON CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) = b.bname
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! It worked, Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid joining altogether, a little less convoluted:

```
Select 
  a.id
  ,concat(a.firstname,' ',a.lastname) as name
  , (select 
        count(*)  
     from table b 
     where a.firstname = n.firstname
     and a.lastname = b.lastname)
from table a
```

count isn't scalar so shoudl work fine.  or just use what you had and make the join ON firstname AND lastname as above (rather than the concatenation)